# How to automatically fill a default value in a sheet cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Form feeding a Google Sheet. Every time a user enters data via the form, a new row is created in the sheet. So far no problem.

I need to assign to each leftmost cell the value `'true'` upon creation. Is there a way to do it in Sheets without the need for Apps Script? I've tried

```
sheet.getRange(1, 1).setValue('true')
```

but nothing happened.

Any help is kindly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried using some formula like this `=IF(B2 != "", "TRUE", "")` this put TRUE if column B is not empty

Comment: With Forms and Sheets, you won't be able to manipulate the feeder/response area.

Answer (score 0):

I have a form feeding into a google sheet, and all I did was make a new column to the left of the first column your form data enters, like so:

[image]

[image]

[image]

After that, **Delete EVERY empty row in your spreadsheet** and add this script to your sheet:

```
function addTrue() {

var AUTOINC_COLUMN = 0; //change this depending on column (A is 0)
var HEADER_ROW_COUNT = 1; //If you have row 1 as form headers, leave this

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var worksheet   = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); //change this to sheet name
var rows        = worksheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
var vals        = worksheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, rows, 2);

 for (var row = HEADER_ROW_COUNT; row < vals.length; row++) {
 try {
     worksheet.getRange(row+1, AUTOINC_COLUMN+1).setValue("true");
     } catch (ex) {
   }  
 }
```

}

You can then set this script to run onFormSubmit so when they finish the form and send data to the spreadsheet, it will add True to it.